# JDK 64bit or 32bit?

Tags: java

My pc is using Windows 7 64 bit. But the server where my jsp web applications will be deployed is 32 bit.

Do I need to install 32bit JDK/JRE in my PC to develop? I'm using Eclipse.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You definitely don't need to install a 32-bit JRE in order to develop. The Java code that you build won't have any trace of your 64-bit-ness. (I'm assuming you're not using JNI, which would complicate matters somewhat.)

You *may* want to install a 32-bit JRE for testing purposes though - to make sure you're not trying to use more than 2GB of memory etc.

Comment: Fair point. You'll probably want to ensure both VMs are from the same vendor though... As one could have bugs the other hasn't ;)

Answer (score 10):

It does not matter. Java is "compile once, run everywhere", so you don't have to develop on a 64-bits platform just because you deploy to a 64-bits platform, or the other way round.

If the stuff works on your PC, it will work the same on your application server, except in one of these situations:

1. You're using JNI (calling "native" code from Java)
2. Either of the VMs has a bug the other doesn't have
3. You code somehow needs to address more memory than a 32-bits process can address.

Answer (score 2):

the bytecode that will result from compilation by your pc with JDK 64bit will be the same as if you had 32bit, the JVM in the application server will run on 32bit - that means, less memory allocation available. If you want to be sure to have the same behavior on memory allocation, you better use the 32bit of the JDK.
In terms of development, both solutions will work.