# Upgrade from 32bit JDK to 64bit JDK

Tags: upgrade, 32bit-64bit, java

I have a question on upgrading the java applications from 32-Bit JDK to 64-Bit JDK.
Is it compatiable to be upgraded like this ?

Could a simple full compilation in 64-Bit JDK using the old java code (.java) achieve it ?

Awaiting your comments on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not using JNI or native code, you should be able to compile your java code with the 64-bit SDK without problems.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9411435/153424 for more information